# fileupload value is not saving in database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

```
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Tbl_Videos(VideoName,VideoPath)values(@VideoName,@VideoPath)");

    string fileExt = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.FileName);

    if (fileExt == ".avi")
    {
        try
        {
            FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/video/" +FileUpload1.FileName));
            Label1.Text = "File name: " +
            FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName + "<br>" +
            FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength + " kb<br>" +"Content type: "+FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType;
           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VideoName",FileUpload1.FileName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VideoPath", FileUpload1.FileName);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Label1.Text = "ERROR: " + ex.Message.ToString();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Label1.Text = "Only .avi files allowed!";
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you able to get the `FileUpload1.FileName` values? & what error you are getting? You need to open the SqlConnection like `con.Open();`

Comment: :After declare `SqlCommand` need to add this given below CommandType mentioned code also `cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;`

Comment: Where is the event that actually sends ( posts ) the file to the server.  You really should check to make sure the file is actually a .avi file, a simple task, to upload an .exe file and just attach a .avi extension at the end.

Comment: con.Parameters.AddWithValue("@path", "video/" +FileUpload1.FileName);
     thnx guys for help....I have find the solution ..i have not write the folder name

Answer (score 0):

where have you mention your SQL server connection string ?

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(YOUR_CONNECTION_STRING_HERE); 
con.Open();
```

then execute your query.